# VBA | Reduce Number of Active Sheets Based on Cell Values

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a user interface that allows users to use a maximum of 10 data tabs. On most occasions, the user will use less tabs (lets say 3). I am interested in a code that operates off of a value within the range [P2:P11] for the ten tabs. If a data tab is in use, the box returns "True" but when a tab is not in use, it returns the value of "False."

I would like the user to not have the burden of seeing the other data tabs (4-10) if they only use 1, 2 and 3. (The data tabs are actually labeled 1, 2, 3 etc. for convenience). This macro is meant to operate on a page called "HIDE_ME" that will be hidden when the program is sent out to users. I have created the code for the event below but I cannot get them to operate. Can anyone assist me in locating my error? Many thanks.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If [P2] = "True" Then
Sheets("1").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("1").Visible = False
End If

If [P3] = "True" Then
Sheets("2").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("2").Visible = False
End If

If [P4] = "True" Then
Sheets("3").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("3").Visible = False
End If

If [P5] = "True" Then
Sheets("4").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("4").Visible = False
End If

If [P6] = "True" Then
Sheets("5").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("5").Visible = False
End If

If [P7] = "True" Then
Sheets("6").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("6").Visible = False
End If

If [P8] = "True" Then
Sheets("7").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("7").Visible = False
End If

If [P9] = "True" Then
Sheets("8").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("8").Visible = False
End If

If [P10] = "True" Then
Sheets("9").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("9").Visible = False
End If

If [P11] = "True" Then
Sheets("10").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("10").Visible = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: When I select "run" for the macro, the macro sheet comes up and the macros are not listed for a selection to run.

Comment: Well first off, `Worksheet_Change` is an event, and I believe it needs to remain the name `Worksheet_Change` (You can just add more underneath that one macro). And this type of macro is placed in the specific sheet in Excel, and whenever something changes in your worksheet, it might or might not trigger this macro.

Comment: In short, there's no need to go to Macros and click "run" - nothing will happen, because this macro isn't made to do anything unless a change is made to your sheet.

Comment: Okay, I will try and test that out real quickly. Thank you.

Comment: @dwiorny, I made some changes and adjusted the cells a bit but the pages are still present. Is there a different way to code this instead so that *if* they put a value into the box, then the tab will appear? I guess that could make the code a little easier.

Comment: Hi @dwiorny, thank you for speaking with me about this. I realized I was making the process too complicated and made a different sub that answered my questions!

Comment: Glad to hear. Good luck on the rest of your project-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub DataSheetsShown()
'Test whether or not the cell value is present
'If value is present, show field
    If IsEmpty(Range("P2").Value) = True Then
        Sheets("1").Visible = False
    End If
    If IsEmpty(Range("P3").Value) = True Then
        Sheets("2").Visible = False
    End If
    If IsEmpty(Range("P4").Value) = True Then
        Sheets("3").Visible = False
    End If
    If IsEmpty(Range("P5").Value) = True Then
        Sheets("4").Visible = False
    End If
    If IsEmpty(Range("P6").Value) = True Then
        Sheets("5").Visible = False
    End If
    If IsEmpty(Range("P7").Value) = True Then
        Sheets("6").Visible = False
    End If
    If IsEmpty(Range("P8").Value) = True Then
        Sheets("7").Visible = False
    End If
    If IsEmpty(Range("P9").Value) = True Then
        Sheets("8").Visible = False
    End If
    If IsEmpty(Range("P10").Value) = True Then
        Sheets("9").Visible = False
    End If
    If IsEmpty(Range("P11").Value) = True Then
        Sheets("10").Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```